# How to test if <div> with a given id attribute has a given link using mockMvc, .andExpect() and xpath?

Tags: spring, xpath, matcher, mockmvc

I am not very familiar with testing a view with mockMvc and I struggle to find a relevant material online. If you know any good tutorials please share here, I will be really grateful.

Let's say the page has:

```
<div id='foo'>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="path"></a>
</div>
```

How can I check if the div element with id 'foo' has an element with href="path"?

My failed attempt:

```
@Test
public void testPage() {
    mockMvc.perform(
        get("/page"))
        .andExpect(xpath("//div[@id='foo']//a[contains(@href,'/path')]"));
}
```

This does not work for me, as I get an error under .andExpect() - "Cast argument 1 to ResultMatcher"

Please could anyone let me know how to test that?

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal example (from line 0 to last line) reproducing the compilation error, and post the **exact and complete** error message from the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a proper way to test if a div with a given id attribute has a given link (I was missing `.exists()`):

```
  mockMvc.perform(
            get("/page"))
            .andExpect(
                    xpath("//div[@id='foo']//a[contains(@href,'/path')]")
                    .exists());
```